# RxJava: How to prepend startWith() default emit EVERY TIME parent observable emits?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

im trying to have a pattern, where my observable which produces some object, is transformed into domain events like Started, Success, Error emited around the observable producing, if that makes sense

```
public Observable<BookRenderingEvent> extractAndRenderObservable(String epubPath) {
        return extractObservable(epubPath)
                .flatMapObservable(extractedEpub -> renderObservable(extractedEpub)
                        .<BookRenderingEvent>map(renderedEpub -> new BookRenderingEvent.Success(renderedEpub))
                        .onErrorReturn(t -> new BookRenderingEvent.Error())
                        .startWith(new BookRenderingEvent.Started()));
    }

private Observable<RenderedEpub> renderObservable(ExtractedEpub extractedEpub) {
        return Observable.combineLatest(readerConfigObservable(), pagerDimensionsObservable(), ..)
                    .switchMapSingle(foo -> doRenderObservable()) <--- heavy work
                    .map(bar -> new RenderedEpub(bar))
}
```

renderObservable contains a heavy action so I want to emit these state events, so UI can react accordingly (with success containing the extractedEpub object as you can see in the map)

What my problem is that, renderObservable contains combineLatest(), so it "stays open" and emit mutiple times in time, whenever its obervables emit.

**So the flow of events is Started, Success, Succes ... Success.**

***I want it to be Started, Success, Started, Success .. etc.*** i.e prepend Started event whever combineLatest emits, but my rx knowledge is insufficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the following into the observable chain at the right place:

```
.flatMap( event -> Observable.just( new BookRenderingEvent.Started(), event )
```

This will emit the `Started` event before every event that it receives.

Of course, you could add in some logic so that you don't issue `Started` if the event is `Started`, etc.

Comment: where would you put it please? im out of ideas .. guessing its need to go after the combineLatest, to trigger on every emit, but then how would I also run the doRenderObservable?

Comment: Right where you currently have the `startWith()`

Comment: that would make Success come before Started

Comment: No. `Observable.just( Started, event)` emits `Started` followed by the event.

Comment: ooh i didnt notice the event on the end

Answer (score 0):

Ok Ive managed to figure it out. The key info I was missing is that right side of flatmap gets subscribed when left side emits. Therefore the startWith had to be moved to the right side of flatmap observable, that gets subscribed to when ever combineLatest emits

```
public Observable<BookRenderingEvent> extractAndRenderObservable(String epubPath) {
        return extractObservable(epubPath)
                .flatMap(extractedEpub -> Observable.combineLatest(readerConfigObservable(), pagerDimensionsObservable(), ..)
                        .switchMap(foo -> renderObservable(extractedEpub)
                            .<BookRenderingEvent>map(renderedEpub -> new BookRenderingEvent.Success(renderedEpub))
                            .onErrorReturn(t -> new BookRenderingEvent.Error())
                            .startWith(new BookRenderingEvent.Started()));
    }
```